# Automate a page using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I want to enter text in my search field but it is not working.

```
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
'/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/
div[4]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/
div/span/div/div[1]/div/input')
search_bar.send_keys("marketing")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

I tried to search but it was closing the browser without searching.

Comment: Can you share the URL of the application if it can be accessed public? If not share the HTML of the desired element and around it. Also share the error trace log from the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an updated version of Selenium for Python, then the `find_element_by_xpath` method will not work due to it being deprecated.

The correct way would be to use the `By` abstract class to choose which property the driver uses to find the element. This can be done like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

search_bar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/span/div/div[1]/div/input')
```

As Tal Angel already mentioned though, it is better practice to use the shortened xpath for readability. More details on this can be found for Selenium in Python in this [*documentation*](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).

Answer (score -1):

You are not suppose to search for elements using such a long Xpath expression. The whole idea of UI test is to work smart, not hard.

If you see the you Xpath expression contains so much `div` or `span` - it is a wrong idea to use it.

if it is your only input field in the page just do this:

```
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
'//input')
```

otherwise, try to locate this input by ID or specific class:

```
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
'//input[@id="inputIDHere"]')
```

Also, before you click on an element or type text on it - make sure it is not null.